# How to calculate this integral with exponential e?

Tags: calculus

How to calculate the integral $\int_0^1 2(e^{2t}+e^{-2t})dt$ ?

Can anyone explain it step by step?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus. This is in every calculus textbook.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -1):

$$2(\mathrm e^{2t}+\mathrm e^{-2t})=4\cosh(2t) \\ \int_0^1 4\cosh(2t)\mathrm dt=4\left(\frac{1}{2}\sinh(2t)\right)\bigg|_{t=0}^{t=1} \\ =2\sinh(2)=\mathrm e^2-\frac{1}{\mathrm e^2}\approx 7.253721$$